# Side bar for ASP.NET MVC6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 6
How can I create a side bar for navigation ? I'm using a layout.
Note that MVC 6 includes Bootstrap.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a layout for your application and in the layout implement your sidebar. Read more [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/721055/ASP-NET-MVC-Layout-and-Section-in-Razor).